# Is there a way in access to make edits (who are made in a subform) link to another table in a database that has a unique ID structure?

Tags: vba, ms-access, data-structures, filter, subform

I have created a database with a unique ID structure. In a form I have a subform that is filtered by a tagname that you can choose in the form with a combobox. When this combobox updates, the subform updates with the data that belongs to this tagname. The problem I am having is when editing the subform. This is because the table structure is set so that the Tagname_ID is linked with the Parameter_ID.  And the Parameter_ID with the Parameter description (see image).

[image]

Now my subform is partially connected to the table tblParameters (see image).

[image]

When I edit something in the subform, it edits it in the tblParameters in the row with the corresponding Parameter_ID, but what I would actually like is that you can choose an existing parameter from the table tblParameters and the form will link the Paramter_ID to the associated tagname. I wouldn't know how to make this without changing my database structure. Any idea how this might work?

Comment: So you don't want to bind form directly to table? Why not? Can use VBA to apply filter criteria to form by setting Filter and FilterOn properties. This is true whether RecordSource is table, query, or SQL statement. Or can use a dynamic parameterized query object and maybe not need VBA (I don't used dynamic parameterized queries).

Comment: The subform can be directly linked to a table, in this case the only problem is, that the tables are updated incorrectly. <br>

So for example:
For editing
- Parameter_ID = 1
- Parameter description = Inom

After editing 
- Parameter_ID = 1
- Parameter description = Test

This is not what I want to happen. I would like to see that after editing, for example, Parameter_ID 2 is associated with the tagname.
In the subform, the controls need a controlsource, therefore the wrong table is updated, when i change the discription in the subform.

Comment: The link line between tblParameter and tblTagname_And_Parameter looks backwards. Appears to be many-to-many relationship with tblTagname_And_Parameter as the junction table. Conventional form design for data entry would be: 1) main form bound to tblTagname and subform bound to tblTagname_And_Parameter with combobox to select parameter or 2) main form bound to tblParameter with subform bound to tblTagname_And_Parameter with combobox to select tagname or 3) single form bound to tblTagname_And_Parameter with comboboxes to select tagname and parameter.

Comment: What you currently have appears to be a form bound to a query that may include joined tables and control is bound to wrong field.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking all the time that your controlsource should be linked to the parameter, but of course it can also be linked to an idea and show a description.